# Modifying a column in a dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

can you please tell me about this question: I have a dataframe

[image]

I want to do the following with it: if the line in the proba column is nan, then change the value in the corresponding line in the flag column to 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `isna` and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['proba'].isna(), 'flag'] = 0
```

Or `np.where`:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['proba'].isna(), 0, df['flag'])
```